# python scikit learn hyperparameter tuning with out of core learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, large-data

currently I am using

`clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log', random_state=1, n_iter=1)`

for my training a prediction model. However, the training data is quite large so I am using out of core learning.

`clf.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=classes)`

Also, I would like to implement hyperparameter tuning through for instance `GridSearchCV`(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

But it seems, as `GridSearchCV` does not provide a partial_fit method, that out-of-core learning is not possible and I have to keep the entire data set in memory. Is there a way for hyperparameter tuning while still using out-of-core learning?

Comment: Hi Micha, did you solve find a solution to the problem?

Comment: @manishthapliyal unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: I found a way to do incremental learning using Random Forest there is a library called scikit-graden they have a Mondarian classifier that adds incremental or online learning to Random Forest

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do incremental learning using Random Forest there is a library called scikit-graden they have a mondrian classifier that adds incremental or online learning to Random Forest.

Check this blog on mondrian forest:
https://medium.com/mlrecipies/mondrian-forests-making-random-forests-better-and-efficient-b27814c681e5